# Autolink action tracking in texview onClickListner

Tags: android

I have a listview ,each item is a textView  with property autoLink="web|email".Link will work properly,but I want to start another activity when text other than web|email is clicked,that was not happening.So I used setOnClickListner for textView,that also worked smoothly.My problem is when I click the email or web link both actions will occur -browser and other activity will open.How to prevent this?

Comment: i think you should open link using  ACTION_URI...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solutions.
I used `getSelectionStart()` and `getSelectionEnd()` functions of the Textview class,

```
  textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
                        @Override 
                        public void onClick(View v) {                              
                                 if(textView.getSelectionStart()==-1&&textView.getSelectionEnd()==-1){
                                 //This condition will satisfy only when it is not an autolinked text 
                                 //onClick action
                                 } 

                        } 
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**TRY this ::**

**in layout ::** `android:autoLink="web"`

**OR**

```
  TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
  t2.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```